# How to keep only one standard currency symbol ($) when changing cultures?

Tags: c#, globalization

How can I make the web app only to display currency in dollars, regardless of the language/country selected ?

```
SetCulture(string culture)
   {
     CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
     CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
   }  


Text = String.Format("{0:C}", item.TotCostDay);
```

Comment: pass the appropriate culture information into the formatter

Comment: There isn't any point left in using the C format specifier when you only want dollars.  So use "${0:N2}" instead.

Comment: @ Hans Passant You are right and it is an alternative. But using the accepted answer I don't have to change the format string on maybe hundreds of places in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a `Clone` of current culture with `NumberFormat.Currency...` modified:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone() as CultureInfo;

CultureInfo usCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

// Dollar symbol - $
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = usCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;

// And (may be) some US currency patterns
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = usCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits;
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = usCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern;
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = usCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern;

CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
```

Comment: Your code worked flawless. I just needed to add this line at the end: CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture2;